# Set margin for every second element in media-query CSS with previously set margin for every third elemt

Tags: css, media-queries, margin

Need to set margin for every second element in media-query that previously had margin for every third.

```
.title:nth-child(3n+3) {margin-right:0 !important}

@media screen and (max-width:1160px) and (min-width:900px){
.title:nth-child(2n+2) {margin-right:0 !important}
}
```

the bottom part of the css does not override the top for some reason. It sets margin to the second element but keeps margin settings of the third as previously set in css.

Comment: can u show the sample image which like it be?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reset the `every 3rd element` rule, either wrap it in its own media query or override it:

```
.title:nth-child(3n+3) {margin-right:0}

@media screen and (max-width:1160px) and (min-width:900px){
  .title:nth-child(3n+3) {margin-right: 20px;}
  .title:nth-child(2n+2) {margin-right:0 }
}
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/9woaL5ho/

Demonstration:
[image: CSS reset nth child rule]

Replace `20px` with original value, because using `inherit` will make it 0. And please avoid using `!important`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but this does not solve the problem as I need to keep the !important part in the previous element

Comment: Then unfortunately you'll have to add `!important` to the new rules as well.

Comment: maybe create a jsfiddle so someone can help you better. The solution mentioned should work, maybe you have other rules that have more specificity

Comment: Have a look at the jsFiddle I created - it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9woaL5ho/ and here is a demonstration GIF: http://i.imgur.com/TvUTHkd.gifv

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle, but it does not work even there

Comment: what browser and operating system are you using? do you have a screen size that has a minimum width of 900px?